SFMC Push SDK - Registration Confirmation
Has anyone found a mechanism for confirming the push registration is actually successful in SFMC via the SDK or via App?
As per the documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/mobilepush/guide/contact-device-registration.html

Registrations are asynchronous. While the SDK can receive a successful 201 response from the server indicating that it received the registration, it can’t ascertain whether it successfully processed it (for example, due to invalid data).

There doesnt look like there is any final and absolute confirmation that the registration was successful and the device is now full push enabled resulting in a potential mis-alignment /disconnect between phone push opt in setting and (no) registration in salesforce.
Retrieval of Push status and or the data dictionary (i.e. device id etc..) interacts only with local app cache and not SF  i.e. Even if you subsequently request the PushOptin status (and/or the full data dictionary), the data is retrieved from the app cache and does not interact with SF.
The registration call back does not provide information on registration failures.
Doesn't seem to be an obvious way to truly understand if app is push enabled.

You are correct, there is no way, from the SDK, to "confirm" the registration status. The endpoint for registration is fire-and-forget.
With an "API" application you can query contacts for your Device ID and get back all the contact details, but the scope of this is outside the SDK's implementation.
An example of such a query:
curl -X POST https: //YOUR_TSE.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d $'{"request": {"attributes": [{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Created Date"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Modified Date"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Contact ID"},{"key": "Contact.Contact Key"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.First Name"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Last Name"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.SDK Version"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Application Version"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Application"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.System Token"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Location Enabled"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Proximity Enabled"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Time Zone"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Is Honor DST"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.UTC Offset"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device Language"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Background Refresh Enabled"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device ID"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Hardware ID"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Platform"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Platform Version"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxBoolean"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxDate"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxDecimal"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxEmailAddress"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxLocale"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxNumber"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxPhone"},{"key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxText"}]},"conditionSet": {"operator": "And","conditions": [{"operator": "Equals","attribute": {"key": "MobilePush Subscriptions.Device ID","id": "","isCustomerData": false},"value": {"items": ["DEVICE_ID"]}}],"conditionSets": []}}'

Notes:

Change the URL with your TSE-based URL for AUTH
Change the TOKEN
Change the DEVICE_ID

You'll also want to replace any "MobilePush Demographics" with your own attributes.
An example output:
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 50,
  "count": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "1ec229ed-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "Contact.Contact Key",
          "name": "Contact Key",
          "value": "app.developer@salesforce.com"
        },
        {
          "id": "f9219e9f-1002-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxBoolean",
          "name": "sdkxBoolean",
          "value": "True"
        },
        {
          "id": "04a9debf-1102-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxLocale",
          "name": "sdkxLocale",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "150afd9d-1102-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxPhone",
          "name": "sdkxPhone",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "9680d912-1102-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxDecimal",
          "name": "sdkxDecimal"
        },
        {
          "id": "70312e77-1102-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxEmailAddress",
          "name": "sdkxEmailAddress",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "13d81456-1102-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxText",
          "name": "sdkxText",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "8297ebc6-a7fd-ea11-a2eb-1402ec94c8a5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Proximity Enabled",
          "name": "Proximity Enabled",
          "value": "True"
        },
        {
          "id": "7c97ebc6-a7fd-ea11-a2eb-1402ec94c8a5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.SDK Version",
          "name": "SDK Version",
          "value": "8.2.1.0"
        },
        {
          "id": "8397ebc6-a7fd-ea11-a2eb-1402ec94c8a5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Background Refresh Enabled",
          "name": "Background Refresh Enabled"
        },
        {
          "id": "7997ebc6-a7fd-ea11-a2eb-1402ec94c8a5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device Language",
          "name": "Device Language",
          "value": "en_US"
        },
        {
          "id": "7b97ebc6-a7fd-ea11-a2eb-1402ec94c8a5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Application Version",
          "name": "Application Version",
          "value": "8.2.1-SNAPSHOT.DEBUG : 250010000"
        },
        {
          "id": "1cb945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Contact ID",
          "name": "Contact ID",
          "value": "123456789"
        },
        {
          "id": "1eb945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Created Date",
          "name": "Created Date",
          "value": "7/22/2024 12:37:52 PM"
        },
        {
          "id": "20b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.First Name",
          "name": "First Name",
          "value": "App"
        },
        {
          "id": "22b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Last Name",
          "name": "Last Name",
          "value": "Developer"
        },
        {
          "id": "2cb945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Platform",
          "name": "Platform",
          "value": "Android OS"
        },
        {
          "id": "34b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Time Zone",
          "name": "Time Zone",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "21b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Is Honor DST",
          "name": "Is Honor DST",
          "value": "True"
        },
        {
          "id": "23b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Location Enabled",
          "name": "Location Enabled",
          "value": "True"
        },
        {
          "id": "25b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Modified Date",
          "name": "Modified Date",
          "value": "8/8/2024 9:58:11 AM"
        },
        {
          "id": "2db945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Platform Version",
          "name": "Platform Version",
          "value": "13"
        },
        {
          "id": "33b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.System Token",
          "name": "System Token",
          "value": "some push token"
        },
        {
          "id": "35b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.UTC Offset",
          "name": "UTC Offset",
          "value": "-4.00"
        },
        {
          "id": "e1617c0c-732a-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device",
          "name": "Device"
        },
        {
          "id": "e5617c0c-732a-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Hardware ID",
          "name": "Hardware ID",
          "value": "Google Pixel 4"
        },
        {
          "id": "8a88efec-1002-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxNumber",
          "name": "sdkxNumber"
        },
        {
          "id": "39ee6944-1002-e911-a2c3-1402ec94b1b5",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.sdkxDate",
          "name": "sdkxDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "18b945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Application",
          "name": "Application",
          "value": "GUID AppID"
        },
        {
          "id": "1fb945f3-d31c-e411-947b-ac162db027d0",
          "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device ID",
          "name": "Device ID",
          "value": "DeviceID"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": {},
  "requestServiceMessageID": "8c452cb6-0059-4caf-91b5-99560ebf6516",
  "responseDateTime": "2024-08-13T10:56:37.7449637-06:00",
  "resultMessages": [],
  "serviceMessageID": "98842523-d1c4-46e1-bf10-bb08a9054106"
}

